# How to compare numbers using regular expression in clojure

Tags: regex, clojure

I am wondering how to compare two numbers using regular expression in clojure. For instance, I want to find all the numbers, which are greater than 500 from a sentence. My code is:

```
user=> (re-matches #"(>? 500)" "the numbers are 300,400,500,600,900")
nil
```

I guessed the regular expression, so I think it is not correct. I want the results are 600 and 900, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for fun

```
(?!500)[56789]\d{2,}|\d{4,}
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cF9jI2/1)

Input:

```
the numbers are 300,400,500,600,900
```

Matches:

```
600
900
```

**Explanation**:

`[56789]\d{2,}` matches 500-999
`(?!500)` Negative lookahead [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bI9fA5/1) except 500
`(?!500)[56789]\d{2,}` matches 501-999 (except 500)
`\d{4,}` matches >= 1000
`|` Alternation / OR operand [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ0iC0/1)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! However, I cannot understand why you put `\d{2,}|\d{4,}`. Can you explain it in detail? I would appreciate that!